# Android: элементы в ListView приложения Gmail

Tags: java, android, listview

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как команда гугла реализовала вот такую вещь:

[image]

[image]

Какой элемент размещен под картинкой, у которого приоритет выше чем у клика на итем? 
Я пробовал размещать в итем кнопку и чекбокс, но тогда на итем просто нажать нельзя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При нажатии на элемент списка они юзают [Action Mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.html), который кстати есть уже в support library. Он соответственно имеет ряд каллбеков, которые можно как угодно обработать: показать контекстный экшн бар,посчитать в нем кол-во нажатых элементов, подставить другую вьюху и т.д. Для списка нужно вызвать setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE).

На самом деле штука любопытная, ознакомьтесь с примерами.

Comment: @DroidAlex Спасибо! Думаю это то, что нужно!

Comment: Пожалуйста :)